# Why does the following lambda compile when assigning it to Runnable?

Tags: java, lambda

I have the following piece of code which obviously can not be compiled:

```
jshell> static int counter = 0;
counter ==> 0

jshell> Runnable r = () -> counter;
|  Error:
|  incompatible types: lambda body is not compatible with a void functional interface
|      (consider using a block lambda body, or use a statement expression instead)
|  Runnable r = () -> counter;
|
```

This is understandable, since the signature for the `Runnable`'s `run` is `void run()`. Now, if I have the following lambda, this will compile just fine:

```
jshell> static int counter = 0;
counter ==> 0

jshell> Runnable r = () -> counter++;
r ==> $Lambda$23/0x0000000800c0b260@3941a79c
```

Why does this piece of code compile, knowing that `counter++` will still return an integer?

Also, what makes it more confusing is that this code can also be compiled:

```
jshell> Supplier<Integer> f = () -> counter++;
f ==> $Lambda$22/0x0000000800c0a410@12edcd21
```

I tried compiling the code above using Java 17's jshell.

Comment: Technically the answer is there already: *consider using a block lambda body*. You could not write `{counter;}` (non-existing syntax), and you could not write `{return counter;}` either (function is expected to be `void`. While in the second case you can write `{counter++;}`, and remain being `void`.

Comment: @tevemadar Putting it like this makes sense, thank you. Java can be confusing sometimes. Probably you would want to add this as an answer.

Comment: On a technical level, it is the difference between an expression and an statement. There are certain statements (e.g. variable assignments, increment and decrement) that also have a value and can act like an expression. For furhter information, I recommend reading [this tutorial at `oracle.com` on Expressions, Statements, and Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Runnable`, the returned value is ignored; the main part (why it compiles) is that there is a statement in it.

It does return a value, so it's also a `Supplier`. It also manipulates `counter` (as a side effect), but that doesn't matter for fulfilling the functional interface. .

Answer (score 2):

(Expanding the comment, piggybacking on other answer and comment)

The error message itself provides some guidance if you interpret *consider using a block lambda body* as "consider what would happen if you used a block lambda body".

When you write a block-less lambda function `arguments -> something`, Java will still pick one from two actual blocks:

1. ```
   void somefunction(arguments) {
       something;
   }
   ```

   and (as other answer and comment point out) in this case `something;` has to be a valid statement
2. ```
   sometype somefunction(arguments) {
       return something;
   }
   ```

   where `something` has to be a valid expression, providing a result to return.

The choice is explicit, you personally do it when specifying the type of the lambda itself.

So when you write [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), which has a single `void run()` method, Java tries to create it for you:

1. ```
   void run() {
       counter;
   }
   ```

   this won't work because `counter;` doesn't exist in Java
2. ```
   void run() {
       return counter;
   }
   ```

   this won't work because a `void` method can't `return` a number.

However this latter one would work with [`Supplier<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) which has a single `Integer get()` method:

2. ```
   Integer get() {
       return counter;
   }
   ```

   this method can exist (with the automatic `int`->`Integer` boxing).

And when you have `counter++`, both can exist, (1.) for `Runnable` and (2.) for `Supplier<Integer>`:

1. ```
   class InnerClassForLambda implements Runnable {
       public void run() {
           counter++;
       }
   }
   ```

   increments `counter` and doesn't return anything
2. ```
   class InnerClassForLambda implements Supplier<Integer> {
       Integer get() {
           return counter++;
       }
   }
   ```

   increments `counter` and returns what it was before the increment.

Answer (score 2):

Compare

```
jshell> Runnable r = () -> counter++;
```

with

```
jshell> Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("Hello");
```

and then it makes it easier to understand why the former compiles.

Like `System.out.println("Hello");`, `counter++;` is also a statement.

Now,

```
Supplier<Integer> f = () -> counter++;
```

compiles because `counter++` does return a value.